# Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-hydro, rosserial-python, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . i uplod [this code](https://github.com/grassjelly/ros_braccio_moveit/blob/master/teensy/src/firmware.ino) on arduino mega 2560 .  and run [this launch file](https://github.com/grassjelly/ros_braccio_moveit/blob/master/launch/demo.launch) .
i have this error :

```
Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

baud rate is 115200 . but my servo motors not working .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274607/unable-to-sync-with-device;-possible-link-problem-or-link-software-version-mismatch-such-as-hydro-rosserial_python-with-groovy-arduino/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-04**:
Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many questions asking for help with *the exact same error*. Many questions. The best way to search for a solution is to use Google with the `site` operator and `answers.ros.org`. For example, go to Google and in the search bar enter:

```
<error> site:answers.ros.org
```

and Google will give you results using only this site! (Note: replace `<error>` with your error.)

[Here's the search results for your error](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Unable+to+sync+with+device%3B+possible+link+problem+or+link+software+version+mismatch+such+as+hydro+rosserial_python+with+groovy+Arduino+site%3Aanswers.ros.org&oq=Unable+to+sync+with+device%3B+possible+link+problem+or+link+software+version+mismatch+such+as+hydro+rosserial_python+with+groovy+Arduino+site%3Aanswers.ros.org).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0